# Hue for Standard Hadoop 2.6.0

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue

Has anyone tried and succeeded in building and configuring Hue on a standard Hadoop Installation (no CDH etc.)?
And if so: what versions (Hadoop, Hive, Hue) did you use? Is there a guide somewhere that explains how to do this?

I have tried and run into a bunch of problems trying to get it to work.
After I `make apps` with the `pom.xml` configured for Hadoop 2.6.1 it seems to build successfully, but it doesnt connect to Hive, the Oozie Server wont start and so on...

Any guide I can find online seems to be for CDH and nothing has worked so far.

Im using Os X MountainLion btw. do you know if there is a way to make Clouderas or Hortonworks distribution work on this OS? If so I might try that first...

Answer (score 0):

Hue is compatible with any standard Hadoop, see the guides in the 'Configure' menu of gethue.com, and in particular:

- http://gethue.com/hadoop-hue-3-on-hdp-installation-tutorial/
- http://cloudera.github.io/hue/docs-3.7.0/index.html